# How can I overlap image in css

Tags: css, sass, flexbox, grid, css-position

I nearly spend 4 hours trying to make this layout. I tried absolute positioning but obviously, It's not responsive.

Image is 660px and Right container is 860px.

```html
    <div className="container">
        <div className="image-container">
     <img src={image} />
     </div>

<div className="right-container">
<div className="insde-some-text">

</div></div>
```

Comment: I wouldn't use `absolute` positioning because it isn't responsive.

Answer (score 1):

As far as my knowledge goes, you can only do this by position absolute and then changing the widths at certain breakpoints using media queries.

Answer (score 1):

To add to what Khubaib said, you would want to use `position: absolute` in your `.css` file. Also, using scalable quantities for the boxes will help you for the certain screen sizes that you want your site displayed on.

Also, you can use `position: relative` on blue block and make the attribute `top: -100px` or so. This blue-block will always be relative to its normal position.

```css
.red-block
{
    width: 20rem;
    height: 20rem;
    background-color: red;
    position: absolute;
}
.blue-block
{
    width: 20rem;
    height: 20rem;
    background-color: blue;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 25%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class = "red-block">
    </div>
    <div class = "blue-block">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use this for reference. Simple demonstration using `flex` and `margin`.

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 5%;
  width: 100%;
}

.right-container {
  border: solid red 1px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 860px;
  height: 860px;
  background-color: #e1e1e1;
  text-align: center;
}

textarea {
  height: 80%;
  width: -webkit-fill-available;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.img {
  margin-right: -3em;
  position: relative;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="img">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/660x400/000/fff" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="right-container">
      <textarea placeholder="hello world"></textarea>
      <p>foooooooooooooooooooooo</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```